# Error onwoocommerce hook woocommerce_subscription_payment_complete

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I added this filter in the index of my plugin as I need to update a table when a subscription is made if the user already had a subscription and a questionnaire.

So whenever I checkout there is an error due to this filter.
if the filter is removed it works
if the function has no code it triggers an error
if I try to print the error in the  log with

```
    error_log('Triggered');
```

there is nothing even with this in my config

```
define('wp_DEBUG',  true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
```

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_subscription_payment_complete', 'change_subscription_id', 10, 2 );
```

here is the method

```
function change_subscription_id( $subscription , $order ) {
   error_log('Triggered');

   global $wpdb;

   $tablename = $wpdb->prefix . "questionnaire";
   $userId = $order->get_user_id();

   $sql = $wpdb->prepare("UPDATE `$tablename`  set
                               `idSubscription` = %d,
                               WHERE idMember = %d",
       stripslashes($subscription->ID),
       stripslashes($userId)
   );
   $wpdb->query($sql);
       
}
```

Comment: Perhaps because the `woocommerce_subscription_payment_complete` hook **expects only one parameter** *(the object representing the subscription that just received payment)*. Look [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/action-reference/#woocommerce_subscription_payment_complete).

Comment: that was it thank you